# Dependencies in the jscript file

Tags: 2010, javascript, client-object-model, best-practices

Lets say, I have `custom-dialog.js` that depends on `custom-notifier.js` and this one depends on `sp.js`. What's the best practises to write dependencies inside mine custom `.js` files?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the great SP.SOD to both register dependencies for your files, but also for making sure they load in the correct order.

[Here is a great guide to get started](http://www.ilovesharepoint.com/2010/08/sharepoint-scripts-on-demand-spsod.html),

also [here some from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff410742.aspx).

The easiest way is to, in the file that the other one is dependent on write

```
SP.SOD.notifyScriptLoadedAndExecuteWaitingJobs("FirstScriptFile.js")
```

and then when you reference your scripts:

```
RegisterSod('FirstScriptFile.js', '/_layouts/FirstScriptFile.js');
RegisterSod('SecondScriptFile.js', '/_layouts/SecondScriptFile.js');

RegisterSodDep('SecondScriptFile.js', 'FirstScriptFile.js');
```

the first parameter in the last one being the dependent file, and the second the dependency file.